# angularjs with codeigniter refresh pages

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am new to AngularJS and I am looking for advice on refreshing page. First loaded page which have header and footer goes fine, but other pages which loaded between `ng-view` when I refreshed them it appears without header and footer which have been loaded at the first page only the partial page without styles or scripts.

Here is app.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute',
'oc.lazyLoad'
]);
myApp.config(function($routerProvider, $locationProvider){
$routerProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'Dashboard',// cotroller php file name
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
    resolve: {
        loadAsset: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['assets/js/controllers/DashboardCtrl.js'])
        }]
    }
})
.when('/Groupcontroller', {
    templateUrl: 'Groupcontroller', // cotroller php file name
    controller: 'GroupCtrl',
    resolve: {
        loadAsset: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['assets/js/controllers/GroupCtrl.js'])
        }]
    }
})
locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

and Dashboard controller like

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){
    $this->load->view("home");
}   
}
```

Groupcontroller php file Controller like

```
class Groupcontroller extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('patial/groups');
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're loading the dashboard normally, but the groupcontroller is loading a partial template. Usually those don't include the full html.

To have the full html in a template in CI you usually have to do something like `$this->load->view('header');` and the same for the footer.

Comment: I can't do that because only the partial page should be loaded between `<div ng-view></div>`, so in `home` page I load header and footer, then other pages only the partial

Comment: Oh ok I think you have something wrong with ngRouter or your codeigniter, the pages are coming from the backend right now, but all requests should go to the index where angular will handle them.